# Untrusted Connection issue when running my site in https

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, virtualhost, ssl-certificate

I'm using cloudflare to manage my DNS.  When I visit my site under https:// it displays an "Untrusted Connection".

Is this most likely due to a DNS issue? Or, could it be happening because of a virtualhost issue?  I can supply my virtualhost config if needed.

Comment: NOTE: Cloudflare is more than just a DNS management tool. They are filtering and changing your content.  I would put them into the category of web site performance optimization companies or content delivery networks rather than DNS management.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a CDN for HTTPS data requires special configuration.

The issue is the CDN is presenting their SSL certificate instead of yours.  This triggers a mis-match in the browser.

You will need to contact CloudFlare to see if they support SSL over CDN. Even then, the SSL domain may not be your domain name.  Often this is a wild card CDN domain.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Screen cap]

You have a bad cert installed. Install one for your actual domain.

Comment: That's... an impressive cert list there, none of which apply to the site in question.  The mind boggles.

Comment: That isn't coming from the cert I installed. It must be coming from my DNS provider.

Comment: Client is using a CDN ... that causes all sorts of extra headaches.

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yeah, I have no idea. Maybe my freehand circle isn't lumpy enough.

Comment: the downvote  was my mistake (corrected) -- need to get crumbs out of trackball.

Comment: @mike Except, CloudFlare isn't just a DNS provider. Did you even read what you signed up for or follow any of the instructions on their page? You could start by reading [this](https://www.cloudflare.com/overview).

Comment: sometimes things just say what they mean and mean what they say.

Answer (score 6):

I'd guess you haven't followed CloudFlare's instructions on adding SSL to a domain. It's a paid service.

http://www.cloudflare.com/wiki/How_do_I_add_SSL_support_for_a_domain%3F